how can i create a doc project in gitlab that host xml files and generate html files
need help to create a documentation project in gitlab that host xml files and runs the transformation to generate html files and publish to a given location.
currently we have our xml files in adobe aem and we are trying to host the xml files in gitlab run the pipeline to generate the html files which can be published to our wesbite.
tried converting the xml files to markdown but we face problem with crossreferences and ditavals. so now looking for options to host the xmls in gitlab.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
